# Vim still create backup/swap/undo folder under .cache when set nobackup/noswapfile/noundofile

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I got a strange behavior of vim 8.1 1-279 / archlinux 4.17.14

This is vim under console but I believe there's no different.

Vim force create `~/.cache/vim/{backup,swap,undo}` folders even I `set noundofile nobackup noswapfile` in `.vimrc`

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: From `:h 'backupdir'`: "The directory must exist, Vim will not create it for you." By chance do you have something set in your `vimrc` or a plugin creating these for you? The default for `'backupdir'` is `.,~/tmp,~/` so I think it is unlikely Vim would create a path of `~/.cache/vim`

Comment: Indeed, I start `vim -u NONE` and no `~/.cache/vim` created. How to track what plugin causes it? @PeterRincker

Comment: @TuyenPham Since your problem comes from your `.vimrc` and your question becomes "How to track what plugin causes it?" I'm closing your question as a duplicate since it is exactly what [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1841) is about

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest would be to simply search for the string `.cache/vim`. e.g. `rg -F '.cache/vim` (uses [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)). You can also use `:verbose` and `:set` to find out more information about an option setting, e.g. `:verbose set backupdir?`. Some [more generic debugging advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32409974/438329).

Comment: From `:verbose set backupdir?`: ```backupdir=~/.vim/cache/backup,~/.vim/cache,/var/tmp/vim,/var/tmps
        Last set from ~/.vimrc```. So last set is from `~/.vimrc`, it doesn't find any from other sources.